# Storing the results of pg_query in a table

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

Is it possible to store the results of a query in a table?

For example, I currently run a query using the following approach in `php`:

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM mytable";
$query = pg_query($connection, $sql);
```

I then use `pg_fetch_row()` to access the result and return it to the web-browser. However, I would like to also store the results in a new table. I understand that I could run the same query twice so I would also have:

```
$sql_2 = "CREATE newtable AS SELECT id FROM mytable";
$query = pg_query($connection, $sql_2);
```

I was curious if there was a more efficient way of structuring my queries, so that I could both access the results, and insert the results into a table through just one query.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately the `CREATE TABLE` command doesn't appear to accept a `RETURNING` clause, so that doesn't allow just having that command also return the results.  So you're likely to need to do two queries.

You could swap the queries to create the new table first, then fetch the results by selecting out of that new table.  Accessing that newly created table may be a bit faster than doing the initial query twice since postgres won't need to look over any irrelevant data.  This would also guarantee that the same results appear in both places.

Comment: Doing a seqscan on a newly created table is almost free. There might be some hint-bit setting, but that's about it. I don't see the point of trying to do it all in one query, really.